# Question about Proj of graded ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A=k[x_0, x_1,x_2]$ be a polynomial ring such that $\text{deg}(x_0)=2$, $\text{deg}(x_1)=\text{deg}(x_2)=1$. How can I understand what is $X=\text{Proj}\,A$?

Comment: Find a cover by affines, understand *that*, and then understand how they are glued. In other words, use the definition :-)

Comment: I would go even further. Any description of $\textrm{Proj}(A)$ for any commutative with $1$ graded ring $A$ is based on the definition of $\textrm{Proj}(A)$ (prime ideals of $A$ such that bla bla bla) and on the fact that $\textrm{Proj}(A)$ has an affine covering. There are situations where you can't evade putting your hands in sludge to understand things.

Comment: @user10000100_u, I don't understand why that is going *further* :-)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Because of the *any*. ;-)